# erreur : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: java, windows, swing

i want to add a JFrame from another class named : Home to the another Jframe in class Dashboard , when i click on on button Home must the content of the Home class be in  the mainPnale but when i run it it shows this errer : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
so please help me thanks [image]alote

this is the Dashboard interface when i click on button Home must import the Panel from class Home like the second pic 
this is the interface of class Home
[image]

[image]

this is the function when click on button home from class Dashboard :

```
private void panelHomeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       



    panelcontent.removeAll();
    Home he = new Home();
    panelcontent.add(he);


}
```

and this is the class Home :

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package project;

/**
 *
 * @author MR-INT
 */
public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Home
 */
public Home() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    panelMainContent3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblcontent3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem();
    home_form1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    panelMainContent3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 350));

    lblcontent3.setText("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelMainContent3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelMainContent3);
    panelMainContent3.setLayout(panelMainContent3Layout);
    panelMainContent3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelMainContent3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelMainContent3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(375, 375, 375)
            .addComponent(lblcontent3)
            .addContainerGap(436, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    panelMainContent3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelMainContent3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelMainContent3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(153, 153, 153)
            .addComponent(lblcontent3)
            .addContainerGap(181, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setText("jRadioButtonMenuItem1");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");

    jLabel1.setText("Welcome to the main home");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    jButton3.setText("jButton3");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout home_form1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(home_form1);
    home_form1.setLayout(home_form1Layout);
    home_form1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        home_form1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(home_form1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(home_form1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, home_form1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addGap(318, 318, 318))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, home_form1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(336, 336, 336))))
        .addGroup(home_form1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(347, 347, 347)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    home_form1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        home_form1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, home_form1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(52, 52, 52)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(79, 79, 79)
            .addGroup(home_form1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(157, 157, 157))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(home_form1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(home_form1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Home().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JPanel home_form1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem jRadioButtonMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblcontent;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblcontent1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblcontent2;
public javax.swing.JLabel lblcontent3;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelMainContent;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelMainContent1;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelMainContent2;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelMainContent3;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: extend **JPanel** in home class since you can't put one Frame into another. or else you can use JInternalFrame instead of JFrame in Home class.

Comment: when i user "" public class Home extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame "" it works with no error but showing nothing from the class Home nothing , but when i use JPanel it shows error like this :: """ Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: project.Home.setDefaultCloseOperation "" 

i try it before to use JPanel but when i found that error i switch to find another solution

Comment: You should not use a JInternalFrame. That was not the suggestion. You should not use an IDE to generate your code. You are not in control. Instead code your classes by handed and use the IDE to help organize the classes an debug the code. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). Download the `TextDemo.java` sample code as an example of how to structure your code. Note how the class extends JPanel, so the panel can be added to any JFrame.

Comment: Try with JPanel.

Comment: when i use JPanel it shows error like this :: """ Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: project.Home.setDefaultCloseOperation "